# prevent TinyMCE 5 from removing empty lines before custom paste_preprocess function

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

How can the input processing be fixed so that line spacing is retained? Using the basic paste plugin.

When pasting this plain text, TinyMCE 5.10.7 (2022-12-06) is removing the empty lines spacing when forced_root_block is set to "div". The lines without alphabet characters should not need a space to keep the line spacing.

```
a no spaces

b

c

d
```

The output from the custom paste_preprocess function(plugin, args) {  console.log(args.content); }

`<div>a no spaces</div><div>b</div><div>c</div><div>d</div>`

When forced_root_block is set to "" (empty), the paste_preprocess console.log is the desired value that retains line spacing.

`a no spaces<br><br>b<br><br>c<br><br>d`

forced_root_block is set to "div" to get formatting and alignment behavior working as expected. Without it, formatting changes apply to more than the selected text.

Is there another hook/event before the input plain text is altered to have HTML?

These are the options I tried:

```
//   forced_root_block: "div",
  forced_root_block: "",

  paste_preprocess: function(plugin, args) {

    console.log('content before: '+args.content);

    args.content = args.content.replace('<br><br>', '<br> <br>'); // + " regex1";
    args.content = args.content.replace('<br /><br />', '<br /> <br />'); // + " regex2";

    // args.content = args.content.replace(/\n\s*\n/, "\n \n") + " regex 3";

    console.log('content after : '+args.content);

  },
  paste_enable_default_filters: true,
  toolbar: ['undo redo | forecolor backcolor fontsizeselect bold italic underline strikethrough link alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify paste pastetext code'],
```

Other TinyMCE options did not resolve the behavior while keeping forced_root_block set to "div". The plain text toggle did not alter the result in this case.